# Call to a member function as_array() on a non-object kohana php 5.4

Tags: php, kohana

I get this error ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function as_array() on a non-object

here is my code using kohana php

```
$query = 'SELECT * from siteinfo' .( ' WHERE id = \'' . 1 . '\'' );
    $result = Db::query( 'SELECT', $query )->execute(  )->as_array(  );
 //$result = Db::query( 'SELECT', "SELECT * from siteinfo" )->execute(  )->as_array(  );
 //print_r($result);die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is:

```
$result = DB::query( Database::SELECT, $query )->execute(  )->as_array(  );
```

BTW: You should use query builder (automatic param escaping)

```
$result = DB::select()->from('siteinfo')->where('id','=', 1)->execute()->as_array();
```

or parametrized queries:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from siteinfo  WHERE id = :id' ;
$result = DB::query( Database::SELECT, $query )->execute(Array(':id'=> 1))->as_array(  );
```